# Python- how to read file line by line, between two lines with certain values

Tags: python, xml, file-io

I am working on a Python program that will take a log file (XML) generated by another program, and read the data from that, extracting just the information that I want, and printing it to the console/ writing it to another file.

The log file that I am reading from contains data (a number of logs) that has been written to it in a certain format, such as:

```
2017-05-01 00:00:24 [Client/Report Report] INFO     {'message-id': 'ID:ELX-LVL-ETL01-50079-1493596823959-1:1:1:1:1', 'expires': '1493640024119', 'type': 'MID', 'persistent': 'true', 'destination': '/topic/bmrsTopic', 'timestamp': '1493596824119', 'subscription': 'TtJXJBbtEOcpLrjDsbFD', 'priority': '4'}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<msgGrp>
    <pubTs>2017-05-01 00:00:24:GMT</pubTs>
    <flow>MID</flow>
<msg>
    <subject>BMRA.SYSTEM.MID</subject>
<row>
    <MI>APXMIDP</MI>
    <SD>2017-05-01 00:00:00:GMT</SD>
    <SP>2</SP>
    <M1>30.620</M1>
    <M2>456.3000</M2>
</row>
</msg>
</msgGrp>

2017-05-01 00:00:39 [Client/Report Report] INFO     {'message-id': 'ID:ELX-LVL-ETL01-59269-1493596838709-1:1:1:1:1', 'expires': '1493640039019', 'type': 'NONBM', 'persistent': 'true', 'destination': '/topic/bmrsTopic', 'timestamp': '1493596839019', 'subscription': 'TtJXJBbtEOcpLrjDsbFD', 'priority': '4'}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<msgGrp>
    <pubTs>2017-05-01 00:00:38:GMT</pubTs>
    <flow>NONBM</flow>
<msg>
    <subject>BMRA.SYSTEM.NONBM</subject>
    <TP>2017-05-01 00:00:00:GMT</TP>
<row>
    <SD>2017-05-01 00:00:00:GMT</SD>
    <SP>2</SP>
    <NB>0</NB>
</row>
</msg>
</msgGrp>

2017-05-01 00:00:41 [Client/Report  Report] INFO     {'message-id': 'ID:ELX-LVL-ETL01-35161-1493596840568-1:1:1:1:1', 'expires': '1493640040868', 'type': 'INDO', 'persistent': 'true', 'destination': '/topic/bmrsTopic', 'timestamp': '1493596840868', 'subscription': 'TtJXJBbtEOcpLrjDsbFD', 'priority': '4'}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<msgGrp>
    <pubTs>2017-05-01 00:00:40:GMT</pubTs>
    <flow>INDO</flow>
<msg>
    <subject>BMRA.SYSTEM.INDO</subject>
<row>
    <TP>2017-05-01 00:00:00:GMT</TP>
    <SD>2017-05-01 00:00:00:GMT</SD>
    <SP>2</SP>
    <VD>21627.000</VD>
</row>
</msg>
</msgGrp>
```

I want to read all of the information between each of the `<msgGrp>` & `</msgGrp>` tags (i.e. the actual XML), and append that to a String, which will then be converted to an XML Tree.

I have started writing the Python script to do this, and do have it reading some of the information correctly. I'm now at the point where I want to read everything between those two XML tags, and append them to a string, but I can't quite figure out how to do this... My Python program currently looks like this:

```
with open("logFile") as file:
    for line in file:
        if(line.startswith('2017')):
            # Do something
            # Display some output in the console
        elif(line.startswith('<?xml')):
            # Do something else
            # Display some output in the console
        elif(line.startswith('<msgGrp>')):
            xmlString = "";
            while(not(line.startswith('</msgGrp>'))):
                xmlString += line;
            # Display some output in the console
        else:
            # Do something else
```

When I try and run this script, the console output shows that the first `if` & `elif` run successfully (I get their debug displayed in the console), but then when it runs into the second `elif` (i.e. the one I'm currently working on- to read the data within the XML tags), the console appears to 'freeze' for a while, as if it's not doing anything, before eventually displaying a message that says:

> Killed

I'm guessing that this is because it's run out of memory or something while reading the lines between those tags and appending them to the variable `xmlString`, (i.e. the code within the second `elif`)...?

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here? How can I get my program to successfully read only the information between the two tags I've specified, and append that all to the `xmlString` variable I've created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   while(not(line.startswith('</msgGrp>'))):
        xmlString += line;
```

that's an infinite loop (`line` is modified in the outer loop, not in the `while` loop), eating all the memory of your machine.

Your logic is broken here. You should set a flag when encountering start of tag, and accumulate until the end of tag *in the main loop*, some logic like:

```
    elif(line.startswith('<msgGrp>')):
        start = True
        xmlString = ""

    elif(line.startswith('</msgGrp>'))):
        start = False

    if start:
        xmlString += line
```

note that:

- it's already bad to concatenate strings, better use `io.StringIO` or list+join)
- using a proper XML/HTML parser is not that difficult and is recommended. Parsing XML/HTML like text is likely to break at some point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A couple of follow-up questions: why is that an infinite loop? There is a line that starts with `</msgGrp>` a few lines further down- so I would expect the `while` loop to stop when it reaches that line. I am expecting the `while` loop to start at the line beginning `<msgGrp>`, and read every line, appending that line to the variable `xmlString`, until it reaches a line beginning with '</msgGrp>`, at which point it should stop reading the lines from the file.

Comment: If I remove the `while`, and just do `xmlString += line;` directly within the `elif`, I just end up appending the line `<msgGrp>` to the string over and over...